# How to link a HTML5 canvas model with a MVVM/MVP data framework

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, canvas, knockout.js

After numerous occasions of trying to clear my thoughts on this matter I thought it'd be best if I turn to some experts who might be able to point me in the right direction.

The concept is as follows, a rather basic idea in concept:

1. The latest data is retrieved from the database from the server side at regular intervals.
2. This data is put into a model managed by something like Backbone.js, Ember.js or KnockoutJS.
3. On the update the elements on the canvas are updated with the relevant information (the canvas is managed by something like KineticJS or Fabric.js).
4. The potential to reverse this process, sending data back up to the server from changes on the canvas.

**So my question is this**: is it practical to link the canvas model (that of the canvas library) with that of one of the MVVM/MVP models? The ones I've looked at seem to focus on HTML elements (and I've dabbled with KnockoutJS previously in that context) but this time I'm trying to manage canvas elements instead. If it is (or isn't) possible, or if a home grown solution is required, what should I look out for, what pitfalls are there, what may I have I missed or forgotten?

It seems [something similar came up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673220/how-to-bind-a-backbone-js-click-event-to-a-view-rendered-inside-a-html5-canvas) just under a couple of years ago, has it changed since then or is it still a matter of home growing the solution? Can the answers in there be expanded upon?

I'm not looking for complete solutions, but for someone who has some experience under their belt to give me some direction (I'm the only one within work who has any experience in this area at all and without anyone to talk it through with or, to even grasp an understanding of it, I'm running myself in circles).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is a great answer, and I am curious to hear if there are any alternatives out there.  But, I recently did something very similar to what was suggested in the link you provided.

If you look at Backbone View, there is not a whole lot going on aside from DOM management stuff, which like you said is useless for canvas elements.  So, I made a simple object in a style similar to Backbone's View to use with canvas elements (I used easel.js).

I can't claim this code is complete or anything, since I was just playing around with easelJS a bit...

```
var CanvasView = function(options) {
        this.model = options.model;
        this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    };
_.extend(CanvasView.prototype, Backbone.Events, {
    initialize: function(options) {
        // in extended view, hook up to model change events, etc.
        // Since I used easel, here I also created some easel DisplayObjects,
        // then update their positions/etc. in response to model changes.
    }
});
```

I think if I ever work on this more, there would be more stuff added, like an easel 'container' built in and possibly a declarative event hash similar to Backbone View's.

Answer (score 1):

I do think you could do this, with a bit of work.

I've hooked up Raphael.js elements to a view model, using [custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), and you could communicate from your canvas element click event (assuming that it has this) to your view model using a pub/sub framework. I'd recommend the [jQuery pubsub](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEkQFjAC&url=https://github.com/phiggins42/bloody-jquery-plugins&ei=mwYaUeT8Meik0AW32ICoAQ&usg=AFQjCNGV8Y2tCgfxdLw-x_AUrMOQc26C1Q&sig2=Zn8xgucCP0uCbQoo6QCDpQ&bvm=bv.42261806,d.d2k) plugin for this.

I've got a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UgyRg/17/) up you can look at for reference, though please note that I created that to demonstrate a problem I had where I have to destroy re-create the canvas elements if you navigate away from the view and come back, so it's not perfect. But you should be able to get the gist of it.

The important sections to look at are the custom binding in the html code:

```
<div class="span10" data-bind="foreach: Current">
    <div class="gauge" data-bind="createGauge: $data"></div>
</div>
```

The custom binding js code:

```
// Knockout handler to create a gauge for each bound item
ko.bindingHandlers.createGauge = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(viewModel.updated);
        var gaugeName = viewModel.Name;
        var substation = bindingContext.$parent;

        var gaugeObject = substation.Gauges[gaugeName];

        // I cannot, for the life of me, get the gauge to redraw properly if I just
        // redraw the inner. Leave the real-time values page and come back, and
        // all the gauges are no longer visible.
        // So destroy the existing one and recreate it from scratch.
        // Yes, this is annoying!
        if (gaugeObject) {
            gaugeObject.gauge.removeChildren();
            gaugeObject.gauge.clear();
            gaugeObject.gauge.remove();
            gaugeObject.gauge = null;
            gaugeObject.paper.clear();
            gaugeObject.paper.remove();
            gaugeObject.paper = null;
            gaugeObject = null;
        }

        if (!gaugeObject) {
            var gaugeSize = $(element).height();
            var paper = new Raphael(element, gaugeSize, gaugeSize);
            var gauge = paper.gauge(viewModel);
            gaugeObject = {
                'paper': paper,
                    'gauge': gauge
            };
            substation.Gauges[gaugeName] = gaugeObject;
        }

        gaugeObject.gauge.updateValue(viewModel);
    }
};
```

The Raphael gauge code (I won't copy it here, it's long, but notice that I only have one observable referenced in that code, otherwise that gauge would get updated for each property that was updated, and I wanted to update all the properties on the view model in one go but only have the gauge redraw once), where I hook the canvas element's click function to the pubsub framework:

```
gauge.clickFunction = function ()
{
    $.publish('/history', [point.IOReference]);
};
```

In my code, that only navigates to a different view, but on the corresponding subscribe handler, you code update your view model and save it back to the server, if you wanted.

Comment: Right, this is a fair bit to take in. Let me get my head around it, in this case you're observing the navigation click event to update the gauges, correct? Using the same concept, of binding using KOJS, could I bind to changes in another model, which is updated via an AJAX request? Or changes within the Knockout model, but then I'd have to redraw the entire canvas would I not? As I'm binding to that, and not to the individual canvas items?

Comment: Well, I'm using the navigation click to go to a different page in the Single Page App, but the principle is the same. It would be your view model that would have a $.subscribe handler that would be notified when the click event fires, and then you can update whatever you want in that model. I've got a far more complicated canvas I've hooked up to KO, and I have a set function in that canvas that takes in the view model, and redraws the parts of the canvas that need updating. If you can access the other view model in the update function, you can bind to it and have it available.

Comment: I have that canvas set up so that it is updated as the result of an AJAX call. Does that make it any clearer? I'm figuring that it probably won't! I'd post some more code, but that canvas is about 2000 lines of js!